# Undefined error of foreach occured out of nowhere (array express node js)

Tags: node.js, api, express, foreach

im using foreach for the array get from url (http://localhost:3000/main?a=aaa.jpg&a=bbb.jpg).
It works before but suddenly stop working.AN undefined cause the error. This is my code:

```
//Define module

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const { exec } = require('child_process');

//extract function
function extract (req,res,next){
    res.write(`filename : ${req.query.a}`);
    const filename = req.query.a;
    console.log(filename);
    filename.forEach((name) => {
        console.log(name);
        exec(`find wi_file/* -type f \\( -name "${name}" \\) -print0 | tar -rvf try.tar --null -T -`,(err,stdout,stderr)=>{
            if (err){
                console.log(`exec error : ${err}`);
                return;
            };
        });
    });
    next();
};

//main function
function main (req,res,next){
    res.write('\nkuor dok \n');
    res.end();
};

app.use(extract);
app.get('/main',main);
app.listen(3000);
```

Some said it may cause by missing ; . I cant identify one. can someone tell me what cause my error. 
[this is the error after run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D7Uj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You `filename` is undefined. That is why it is throwing the error. `filename` must be an `array` then you can use it with `foreach` like you have used above. You can also add the check for that if filename is Array like

```
if(Array.isArray(filename)){
  //do something with filename
}
```

Comment: thank you for enlighten that. I also just find out about that. Am i doing wrong with the assign array? How am i supposed to assign it?

Comment: Assignment is right but data in req.query.a is not an array.